# python poetry how to install for all users ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-poetry

I am trying to install `poetry` for all users on ubuntu 18.04 and it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried the script (which installs to a local user's home directory)

```bash
$ curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
# this works but is only installed for the current user
```

and I've tried pip:

```bash
$ pip install poetry
$ poetry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I also tried manually moving the `poetry` binary into `/usr/local/bin` but there are library dependencies that are not available.

Comment: Did you try adding `export PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"` to your shell configuration file?

Comment: ah that isn't how I solved it, it may work but I will post my own solution, thanks for reminding me about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved it:

```bash
# copy poetry bin and lib to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib
$ cd ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
$ sudo cp -R ./poetry-1.1.13.dist-info/ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
$ sudo cp -R ./poetry_core-1.0.8.dist-info/ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
$ sudo cp -a . /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
$ cd ~/.local/bin
$ sudo cp poetry /usr/local/bin/
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
```